# Android C# Xamarin compile error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am working with Xamarin; it allows C# applications to run on Android. However, I am getting the following error:

> Error 1   The "ResourceNameCaseMap" parameter is not supported by the "AndroidComputeResPaths" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a gettable public instance property.  AndroidApplication1

I Googled the error, but only 1 result comes up without answer. I tried both Visual Studio 2012 and 2010, stock Android application template and I still get the error.

Comment: What project are you trying to run? Please add it to your question, so I can try to answer it. Thanks

Comment: Still have this problem, and theres no help online AT ALL

Comment: it's being discussed here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031824/wierd-error-accurs-when-building-android-project-xamarin?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

"I removed Xamarin android and then reinstall mono-android-4.6.04000.msi, then works fine now!~"

This answer by mousebb on the other thread worked for me....

[Wierd error accurs when building Android project (Xamarin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031824/wierd-error-accurs-when-building-android-project-xamarin?lq=1)

Comment: This work for me.I remove xamarin studio and reinstall mono for android.