# Wierd error accurs when building Android project (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, multiplatform

I'm new to `Xamarin` and multiplatform development. I've downloaded and installed everything as in `Xamarin guide`. I event updated to latest versions. But when I try to build and empty created project, I get an error. I've searched like for a day, and ended up with no result. Does anyone knows what's with this error?

The error itself:

> Error 1, The ResourceNameCaseMap parameter is not supported by the
>   AndroidComputeResPaths task. Verify the parameter exists on the task,
>   and it is a gettable public instance property.

Comment: I was asked to update to 4.6.4 but that didn't work either are you using MonoGame.Android as well? all the samples stopped working there too.

Comment: Linked to this, should try if the alpha channel works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988314/android-c-sharp-xamarin-compile-error

Comment: no, I'm not using MonoGame, I've just installed xamarin with everything (SKD, NDK, etc.). Than I simply created project and tried to build it. That's where the error occured.

Comment: I seem to have the problem with MonoGame, will try again. they'er probably linked.

Answer (score 1):

I removed Xamarin android and then reinstall mono-android-4.6.04000.msi, then works fine now!~

Comment: Will try it. there's also an error here that needs checking http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/665199/nullreferenceexception-in-msbuild